# Displaying a localized JS Date without timezone adjustment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization, angular-moment

My Angular front-end is getting timestamps via REST requests to a server in the same timezone. The server does not store timestamps in UTC. 
I want to :

1. display the date and time in a localized way
2. keep the exact same time displayed (I don't want any timezone adjustments)

For example: 
timestamp string from server : **2017-09-20T17:45:00**

I need to display it localized like this:

```
    mercredi 20 septembre 2017 17:45 (french)
    Wednesday, September 20th, 2017 5:45 PM (english)
```

On 2 different machines, I get different results, even though the OS is configured with the same timezone :
    (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris

On machine 1: 
        Wednesday, September 20th, 2017 6:45 PM // (english) KO !!

On machine 2: 
        Wednesday, September 20th, 2017 5:45 PM // (english) OK

Currently, the code is:

```
jsDate = new Date(dateTimeStr);
localizedDateTime = moment(jsDate).local().format('LLLL');
```

What would be a safe way to *always* get 5:45 PM ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using moment wrong.

- Native javascript `Date` won't necessarily parse that string properly.
- Moment will.

From the moment docs [String + Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

`localizedDateTime = moment(dateTimeStr, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss").local().format('LLLL');`